# "Auto-complete" tags with MapReduce in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, database-schema

**Short version**: I need to get an array of distinct tags matching `/web/` or any other term for that matter, out of the `Posts` collection.

---

I'm having doubts about implementing a MapReduce pattern to feed an "auto-complete" field. Do you think this is the best approach?

My `Posts` collection has documents like:

```js
{
    'title': 'A great post',
    'tags': ['web2.0', 'monetize', 'cloud', 'someOtherDumbTerm']
}
{
    'title': 'Another great post',
    'tags': ['monetize', 'seo-optimization', 'web3.0']
}
```

Given a search such as `/web/`, I'd have results like: `["web2.0", "web3.0"]`

My MapReduce function goes like:

```js
var mapFn = function(){
    if( this.tags ){
        this.tags.forEach(function(value){
            if (value.match(/web/i)){
                emit('web', value);
            }
        });
    }
};
var reduceFn = function(key, values){
    return {result:values};
};

db.runCommand({
    mapreduce: 'posts',
    out: {inline:1},
    map: mapFn,
    reduce: reduceFn,
    query: {tags:/web/}
});
```

I'm thinking about storing tags in a different collection and just do a regular search for them, but I seem to find that the vestigial intuition left by years of RDBMS learning. I also have no idea about performance or other implications for these kinds of queries, and the documentation does not seem to be very useful for this case.

Thanks!

---

## What I ended up doing

I actually only ended up using MapReduce for analytics of said tags.

I store them the way described but on a different collection, taking care of normalizing it to basic ASCII (i.e. no accents and such) for the regex searches, as well as keeping the original terms. I then reference the `tag` object id to the `post` id in another collection.

All of this I turned into a different app to serve different clients. It turned out to be the best solution for my particular need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Map/Reducing the tags into a different collection sounds very reasonable.

You cannot run the Map/Reduce query in real time. And you cannot use standard 'find' queries to get just the tags that you want from your existing collection. And you probably don't care if your tag auto-complete system doesn't include new tags from the last hour or last day or however often your MapReduce job runs.

Comment: I had not thought about that, but maybe that is the best approach: using `out: {merge: "tagIndexes"}` and query that in real time. Thanks!

Comment: I ended up doing a whole different thing, but your answer helped me figure out a good use for Map/Reduce. Thanks!